# Linux does not work with Acer UT220HQL touchscreen

Tags: linux-device-driver, touchscreen

The controller is identified as a TPV OpticalTouchScreen.
The Vendor and Product IDs are: 25aa:8882.

Edit - I corrected the title from "Recognize" to "work with", since I believe the driver attempted to work, the driver/hardware needs a specific tweak to prevent going into a uncommunicative state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin showed me how to apply the same quirk flag as is applied to the TPV model 8883.  And now it works as expected for single touches (I don't use and therefore have not tested multi-touch)

I believe Benjamin will apply the fix into the source code, so eventually this will work automatically.  But to get up and running now, do the following:

Append "usbhid.quirks=0x25aa:0x8882:0x8" into your kernel boot string.  Most people will need to do this in their boot loader (GRUB or similar).  Raspbian users like myself will need to append it in /boot/cmdline.txt

Answer (score -1):

I applied this fix to my Syslinux Append line, digitizer now works.  Two finger scroll works in Chromium as well.  Arch Linux 4.1.5-1-ARCH